# Possibility of confusion caused by the use of $\nabla$

Tags: notation, differential-topology, vector-analysis, laplacian, hessian-matrix

This is a question about notation. Of course, as long as the notation is clearly defined, it doesn't matter at all which notation we use, but it's still helpful to ask about a few possible confusions that can be caused by the usage of $\nabla$.

1. Laplacian. Sometimes, the Laplacian is denote $\nabla^2,$ so $\nabla^2 u = \nabla \cdot (\nabla u).$ Although this seems to justify the use of $\nabla^2,$ the Laplacian is not the only thing that comes from the square of $\nabla$. Another would be the "Hessian" $\nabla (\nabla u).$ (Well, it is the Hessian up to index raising/lowering.)
2. Directional derivative. The $\nabla$ operator comes with two steps: (1) find the derivative of $u$ as a linear form, (2) raise an index to make it a vector, not a covector. So, if we come across a directional derivative of a **vector** like $(\mathbf f \cdot \nabla) \mathbf g,$ although it is **tempting** to drop the bracket to write $\mathbf f \cdot \nabla \mathbf g,$ we run into the problem that $\nabla \mathbf g$ is the tensor product of two vectors, and we do not know with respect to which of the two vectors are we dotting $\mathbf f$ with if we write it without bracket. So this no-bracket notation fails.

Things get increasingly unnatural with many other common combinations of $\nabla$, and in a way, the notations used in differential topology (Lie derivative, exterior derivative, hessian as a 2-form, etc) are much clearer and more effective in avoiding such undesirable temptations described above.

The question I am going to ask is quite general: what are some good ways to avoid these possible confusions, and what recipie of notations or way of thinking would do a better job of avoiding these confusions?  **Although I do understand** how these wired $\nabla$'s work, I personally feel uncomfortable working with notations that lead to such "ambiguity".

Comment: I don’t understand where the ambiguity is. Case 1 there is a dot product in one, not in the other. Case 2 has parenthesis because multiplication and dot product don’t commute. These things are only confusing if you take notation loosely or the print quality is so low the dots are not visible any more.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Let me explain. In case 1 the notation $\nabla^2$ does not tell us explicitly we have a dot product, leaving other possibilities of interpretation. (A square may be taken to mean a dot product, but not always.) We have to write explicitly in words to prevent other interpretation. In case 2 I do not see any multiplication. The point is to discuss what can happen when one takes notation loosely.

Comment: If you ask me, the whole $\nabla$-formalism in vector analysis should be put to rest. Differential forms offer a much neater formalism. Sure, they are a bit confusing at first sight, but so are the strange "Nabla-vector" and the dot and cross product.